# ¿Cómo puedo insertar el texto separado por comas de un elemento en una tabla?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo el texto siguiente en un elemento: 'AC,VE,ME,ED' 
y lo que quiero lograr es insertar esas siglas en 4 registros diferentes.

Estoy usando 'plsql developer 13'.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Este query puede convertirte la lista separada por comas en registros

select regexp_substr('AC,VE,ME,ED','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
  2  connect by regexp_substr('AC,VE,ME,ED', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;

Desconozco donde lo quieres insertar pero puedes hacer algo similar a este:

Insert into table
select regexp_substr('AC,VE,ME,ED','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
  2  connect by regexp_substr('AC,VE,ME,ED', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;